# Extract html nodes having not specific child or tags by HTML Agility?

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack and I have a scnerio where I have to fetch collection of some html nodes from a html document having not **button** tags. Apart from this, I need complete collection of html elements. For Example my html document might be like this

```
<p> This is first free text </p>

<p> <button class='testButton'> this is first button </button> </p>

<strong> <p> This is second free text </p> </strong> 

<button class='testButton'> this is second button </button>
```

Now I need html node collection of first and second free text tags. Currenly I am able to fetch all button nodes/tags collection from the document by using xpath

```
 html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//button[starts-with(@id, 'btn~~')]");
```

Now I need collection of all nodes having other **than button tags** also. Kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

In provided html your xPath won't return anything, cause there is no button with @id attribute.
Still, `@"//*[local-name()!="button"]"` will return all nodes except **button**.

EDIT: All `p` without button inside it `@"//p[not(button)]"`.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working as it is giving me a node for each and every html tag irrespective of that this tag is child of previous tag and giving button tag nodes also.

Comment: But that is exactly what you asked for: " Now I need collection of all nodes having other than button tags also.". For free text without button: `@"//p[not(button)]"`

Comment: Yes i need collection of all nodes excluding button tags. But this is giving me button tags also and its children tags also. While neither I need button nor its children.